# Windows Explorer favorties as buttons?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

I use the favorites in Windows Explorer quite often to gain quick access to deeply nested  folders. But I find it quite annoying always have to click the Favorites button in the menu and then search the favorite I'm lookig for in the dropdown.

Is there anyway to add specific favorites as buttons to Windows Explorer?

I'm using XP x64.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?  In Windows Explorer ...

View > Toolbars > UNcheck 'Lock the Toolbars', if already checked

View > Toolbars > CHECK 'Links', if not already

Now position the new toolbar where you would like it, by grabbing, dragging and dropping

Now you should be able to click on Favorites from the menu then click on the shortcut you would like to make a button, hold and drag that menu item link to the links toolbar.

You should now have a button that will do what you asked for.  :)